# Windows minimized window hidden entirely from screen

Tags: windows, hidden, minimize

I have 3 windows active:
First window: M@ERP System,
Second window: Asset,
Third window: Report/Listing.

I minimized the third window and it is not showing in my taskbar nor the bottom left corner. No indication of a minimized window unless I go to task manager and view the active windows.
This is Windows server 2012.

[image]

I did the same in Windows 11 Pro and I have the minimized window's action bar showing at the bottom left.

[image]

Can someone let me know how to show the minimized window at the bottom left in Windows Server 2012?

Thank you in advance.